# Rails: I need different AdminUsers to have different permissions

Tags: authorization, admin, activeadmin, cancan

So I'll go straight to the point.

I'm using the `ActiveAdmin` gem, so I have the `AdminUser` model in my app... **now I got a requirement from my client where a "super admin" must be able to control the permissions of other administrators**.

So, for example, if I have the resources: `Message`, `Client` and `Country`, the "super admin" should be able to assign to an AdminUser the task of managing messages, to another one the task of managing clients and to another one the task to managing countries.

For this I was thinking about adding several `boolean` attributes to the `admin_users` table. For example, a `boolean` attribute called "super_admin" would be used to determine if this `AdminUser` can change the permissions of other `AdminUsers`, another attribute called message would be used to determine if this `AdminUser` has control (can edit, read, delete, etc.) over the messages, another attribute called country would be used to determine if this `AdminUser` has control (can edit, read, delete, etc.) over the countries and so on...

**What's the problem?** I can't `access` to current_admin_user in models, so I can't do something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Message do
  if (current_admin_user.message)
    permit_params Commune.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym)
  end
end
```

So what can I do? I must build this functionality!

Answer (score 0):

**edit**
I found this gem that adds roles to active admin https://github.com/yhirano55/active_admin_role

why it needs to be in model ? Code looks like it should be placed in controller, permit_params...

I would use **pundit**. I can see **can can** was updated 5 years ago. They are similiar.

pundit repo: https://github.com/varvet/pundit

It uses policies, so you create policy for every model.

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def update?
    user.admin? or not record.published?
  end
end
```

where you can check your flags on update or create or show or anything...

In action you use something like this **authorize @post, :update?**

Quote from their doc

In this case, you can imagine that authorize would have done something like this:

```
unless PostPolicy.new(current_user, @post).update?
  raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "not allowed to update? this #{@post.inspect}"
end
```

Hope it will help

P.S It you need more complex solution. I would create Role model, where I could specify model, read, write permissions. I would link it with my user to **has_many** roles, and in my policy do something like this:

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def get_role
    user.roles.where(model: "Post").first
  end
  def update?
    user.get_role.write? or not record.published?
  end
end
```

Or maybe there is better way to use it somehow in policy model...

Comment: Have you used active_admin gem before? Does this work with active_admin? The super user would be able to edit other people's permissions?

Comment: I think you are searching for this: https://github.com/yhirano55/active_admin_role

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that gem

Comment: Anyway, I would appreciate accepting the answer, I need points

Comment: Sorry for asking then... I thought I found the solution by finding gem, that use cancan gem, without gem I would go pundit way like I post earlier. So how did u implemented it?